# Firebase Realtime Database - multiple sequencial fetch and write operations without nesting promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Realtime database for storage.

In order to update contact data for users when a "Note" is updated I need to perform some **sequential** operations. I wish to update/push contacts nodes to for each "affectedUser" that is included in the "Note".

Below is a crude representation of my database.

```
-notes
  -note123456 <-- Note being updated
    affectedUsers: {'L1234567890ABC': true, 'L0987654321XYZ': true} <-- affectedUsers
-users <-- Compose contact objects from here for all affectedUsers
  -L1234567890ABC
    name
    alias
    email
    avatar
    favouriteColour
  -L0987654321XYZ
-contacts <-- Add new contacts here
  -L1234567890ABC 
    -ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123 <-- Already added contact
      alias
      name
  -L0987654321XYZ
    -ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO0123 <-- Already added contact
```

My starting point is a list of "affectedUsers" that needs to be updated - a list of user Ids.

The desired, simplified, workflow looks like this

1. Iterate "affectedUsers" and compose "contact cards"
2. Then iterate all "affectedUsers" and add contact cards to each affectedUser

My current code

```
const dbRoot = snapshot.ref
affectedUsers = ['-L1234567890ABC', '-L0987654321XYZ']
let promises = [];

affectedUsers.forEach((affectedUser) => {
  const ref = dbRoot.child(`users/${affectedUser}`)
  promises.push(
    ref.once('value', (userSnapshot)=>{
      const userNodeData = userSnapshot.val()
      const contactObject = {
        alias: userNodeData.alias,
        name: userNodeData.name
      }
    return contactObject
  );
})

Promise.all(promises).then((contactObjects) => {
  let updateContactsPromises = [] //Collect second promise chain
  //Check contacts of affectedUsers
  affectedUsers.forEach((userId) => {
    const ref = dbRoot.child(`contacts/${userId}`)
    updateContactsPromises.push(
      ref.once('value', (updateUserContactsSnapshots) => {
        updateUserContactsNodeData = updateUserContactsSnapshots.val()
        //Remove userId from additions, prepare database update object, push data
        //...
      })
    )
  })

  //Execute second, and last promise chain
  Promise.all(updateContactsPromises) //Line 328
  .then(()=>{
    //...
  })
  .catch((err)=>{})
})
.then(()=>{
  //...
})
.catch((err)=>{})
```

I realize nested promises is not a good thing - since I get warnings when performing a firebase deploy. ;)

> 328:9  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
>   328:9 
>   warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
>
> ✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

How can I make sure my calls gets executed sequentially without nesting promises?

Comment: For one thing, you should use `.map` instead of `forEach` followed by `push`. But I'm not immediately seeing anywhere that the nesting could actually be fundamentally be avoided by returning to a `.then` instead, what lines are those warnings shown on?

Comment: Why not just move the inner `.then` to above the last outer `.then`? Its callback does not seem to depend on values that is only available in the first `.then` callback.

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance! Thanks for the tip on .map(). It is the firebase-functions deploy process that shows the error eg. when running "firebase deploy --only functions:onNoteUpdate"

Comment: But which *lines* do those point to in the code? `328:9` points to a line number and a column number

Comment: Hi @GeorgeLeung! Thanks for the tip! Not sure I am interpreting your answer correctly, thought? I am using the result from the first promise ("contactObjects") in the second promise chain "updateContactsPromises".

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance. Sorry for the confusion with the code lines. Lines 328 correspond to the line "Promise.all(updateContactsPromises)".

Comment: Oh, I should have seen that - yes, that's an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you have a `.then` directly inside another `.then`. Usually, this can be fixed by *returning* the next Promise, instead of having a nested then. For example, change

```
prom.then(() => {
  getAnotherProm().then(handleOther);
});
```

to

```
prom.then(() => {
  return getAnotherProm()
})
.then(handleOther);
```

Here, you can return the second `Promise.all` to avoid nesting `.then`s:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((contactObjects) => {
    let updateContactsPromises = [] //Collect second promise chain
    //Check contacts of affectedUsers
    affectedUsers.forEach((userId) => {
      // ...
    })

    //Execute second, and last promise chain
    return Promise.all(updateContactsPromises)
  })
  .then((updateContactsValues) => {
    // handle resolve value of updateContactsPromises
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  })
```

Remember to only `.catch` at a level where you can *handle the error* properly, and you can chain `.then`s together to avoid having to duplicate `.catch`es.

You can also use `.map` instead of `.forEach` to construct the array of Promises all at once, eg:

```
const dbRoot = snapshot.ref
affectedUsers = ['-L1234567890ABC', '-L0987654321XYZ']
const affectedUserPromises = affectedUsers.map((affectedUser) => {
  const ref = dbRoot.child(`users/${affectedUser}`)
  return ref.once('value', (userSnapshot) => {
    const userNodeData = userSnapshot.val()
    return {
      alias: userNodeData.alias,
      name: userNodeData.name
    };
  });
});
Promise.all(affectedUserPromises).then((contactObjects) => {
  // ...
```

Comment: Wow! Many thanks @CertainPerformance - That makes so much more sense :D And a special thank for the clear example!